# What to use instead of after_commit in controller in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby, callback, controller, ruby-on-rails-5

Today I tried to use a wonderful callback :after_commit which triggers when the object is written to database, however, I've got the error message from Rails:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `after_commit' for ImagesController:Class
Did you mean?  after_action):
```

Well, that was embarassing! And it seems like this callback was deprecated!
Looking through search, I tried to use :after_create_commit, which gave me the same error.

The third step was to try :after_action. Here goes the question:
**How to make it work the same way as :after_commit?**

*I've already tried [apidock.com](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/after_action) - it's really minimal! Also I've tried [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html) - it is saying about blocks, but I'm not a ruby ninja to understand it. So I really apprecite if you could spill some light on it!*

ImagesController:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  after_create_commit :take_image_to_album

  def take_image_to_album
    if check_album
      add_inner_to_album(@image)
    end
  end

  def create
    @image = Image.create(image_params.merge(:user_id => current_user.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      unless @image.save
        format.html { render :show, notice: "Error!" }
        format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      else
        format.html
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @image }
      end
    end
  end
  ...

  def add_inner_to_album(image)
    contents = @album.content
    contents << [image.id, image[:imageup], false]
    @album.update(:content => contents)
  end
  end
```

Comment: What's on your ImagesController?

Comment: `after_commit` only applies to models. For controllers you do mean `after_action`. Controllers and models share a common design language, but not necessarily method names.

Comment: @tadman Do you suppose to move this callback and method which belongs to it to the model?

Comment: It depends. Do you think it's the responsibility of the model to do that, or is it something the controller should initiate?

Comment: I think it doesn't belong to model, actually. Because it is eventually updates an album. However, I might be wrong. Could you take a look? I'll update my question in a minute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [after_commit](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit) method is only for models. In the controllers family, you have [after_action](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/after_action), that will be executed after the action of the controller is finished.

For example, the `after_action` in a controller works like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  after_action :log_activity, only: :show

  # GET v3/users/:id
  def show
    render status: :ok,
           json: { id: current_user.id, name: current_user.name }
  end

  def log_activity
    current_user.update(last_activity_at: Time.current)
  end

end
```

The `log_activity` method is executed after responding the request.

In the `after_action :log_activity, only: :show`, with `only` you can specify after which actions `log_activity` will run. If you do not specify any, it will run after every action defined in the controller.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the purpose of the "show_serializer" method?

Comment: I am sorry,  `show_serializer` is an instance of a Serializer class that only has the responsability of returning a hash to be returned. I will change it for something simplier

Comment: Your welcome. I hope my answer helps you. Do you have any doubt?